# Get period from date

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need a oracle SQL query to get period from date column.

These are the conditions:

1. If 1st day of the year i.e 1st jan is Saturday then 1st period start from that day else from the last saturday
2. Each period has 28 days. After 28 days, the next period starts and it continues.

For e.g if the date is 2nd feb 2016 then period should be 2.

Thanks,
Milan

Comment: Show what you tried so far and tell where you facing the issue?

Comment: the problem is I am not able to start...if somebody provide some logic then  I can take from there..

Comment: So what you need is like date range ?

Comment: yes I think i can get period from date range.. Suppose today is 9-jun-2016 , i need the period for this date like 6(calculated manuly).Each period have 28 days.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Typically the easiest and most flexible way is to create a calendar table that stores the period for each date. Even for 100 years this would be quite a small table.

Comment: I am using Oracle db.

Answer (score 0):

This query will run in SQL Server
Plug in the column name and table name in the following query. This is a very rough fix. It needs optimizing, but maybe you can use it as a base:

```
select 
case when 
 datepart(dw, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATECOLUMNHERE), 0)) = 6 then datepart(dy, DATECOLUMNHERE)/28
else datediff(d,DATEADD(d, -2 - (DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATECOLUMNHERE), 0)) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATECOLUMNHERE), 0)),DATECOLUMNHERE)/28
 from TABLENAMEHERE
```

This doesn't consider @@Datefirst in the first check

The query is

```
 select 
  case when FirstDayOfYear = 6(Saturday) then return (number of days in date column) / 28
 else 
   (number of days betwen (last saturday before 01-Jan) and date column) /28
```

Comment: How do you know that `datepart()` or `datediff()` works for Milan? Neither of them are standard SQL functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one for Sql server

```
CREATE Table #YourTable (
    DateColumn date NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #YourTable
VALUES ('20160202')
      ,('20150128')
      ,('20140128')
      ,('20130128')
      ,('20120128')
      ,('20110128')
      ,('20100128')
      ,('20090128')
      ,('20080128');

SELECT *          
FROM #YourTable AS YourTable
     CROSS APPLY (
         VALUES (DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(dayofyear, YourTable.DateColumn), YourTable.DateColumn))
     ) AS CA1(FirstDayOfYear)
     -- Periods starts saturday before first friday of year
     CROSS APPLY (
          VALUES ((20 - @@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(weekday, FirstDayOfYear)) % 7)
     ) AS CA2(DaysUntilFriday)
     CROSS APPLY (
         VALUES (DATEADD(day, DaysUntilFriday - 6, FirstDayOfYear))
     ) AS CA3(PeriodStartDate)
     CROSS APPLY (
         VALUES(DATEDIFF(day, PeriodStartDate, YourTable.DateColumn))
     ) AS CA4(DaysSincePeriodStart)
     CROSS APPLY (
         VALUES ((DaysSincePeriodStart + 0) / 28 + 1)
     ) AS CA5(PeriodNumber)
```

Output

```
| DateColumn | FirstDayOfYear | DaysUntilFriday | PeriodStartDate | DaysSincePeriodStart | PeriodNumber | 
|------------|----------------|-----------------|-----------------|----------------------|--------------| 
| 2016-02-02 | 2016-01-01     | 0               | 2015-12-26      | 38                   | 2            | 
| 2015-01-28 | 2015-01-01     | 1               | 2014-12-27      | 32                   | 2            | 
| 2014-01-28 | 2014-01-01     | 2               | 2013-12-28      | 31                   | 2            | 
| 2013-01-28 | 2013-01-01     | 3               | 2012-12-29      | 30                   | 2            | 
| 2012-01-28 | 2012-01-01     | 5               | 2011-12-31      | 28                   | 2            | 
| 2011-01-28 | 2011-01-01     | 6               | 2011-01-01      | 27                   | 1            | 
| 2010-01-28 | 2010-01-01     | 0               | 2009-12-26      | 33                   | 2            | 
| 2009-01-28 | 2009-01-01     | 1               | 2008-12-27      | 32                   | 2            | 
| 2008-01-28 | 2008-01-01     | 3               | 2007-12-29      | 30                   | 2            |
```

Comment: Cross apply , dateadd and datediff won't work in oracle. Any alternative?Logic is correct by the way.

Comment: Hi Adrianm, Can I have the same logic for oracle. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Milan6687, sorry, I don't know Oracle. Try to add an `Oracle` tag to summon the experts.